# Get Property's value by using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to get column property's value by using entity framework in c#.

My Code:

```
 foreach (var columns in _context.Properties)
{
  var SelectedColumnValue = columns.GetType().GetProperties().GetValue(0)GetType();
}
```

How can i get value of propert(fieldname/column name) in entity framework ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking for.

Comment: columns.GetType().GetProperties().GetValue(0) code gives me column name  from table. I want to reach column's value

Comment: IMHO you need better understanding of how to work with EF. I found this [EF tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSwbmc5-y0w&index=2&list=PL9E3058F81E2A9088) by Julie Lerman on Youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where to start. If `_context` is of type `DbContext`, `Properties` wouldn't have worked unless you have a table named `Properties`. So `_context` is probably `typeof(DbContext)`. Then again, `Type` class does not have a property named `Properties` but it has the `GetProperties()` method.

In that case, each `columns` would be an instance of `PropertyInfo`. Then you could have used `columns.Name` to get the name of that property. Those names would have nothing to do with columns, but they would probably be pluralized names of tables.

---

tl;dr

I'm lost.